# Get encoded region name-HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm using hbase 0.94.0. I'm trying to use the follwing function

```
public void move(byte[] encodedRegionName,byte[] destServerName)
```

I retrieved `destServerName` using `getServerName` function.

Now how do i get the `encodedRegionName`? Is there any API for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

getOnlineRegions() or getTableRegions() methods for HBaseAdmin class can give a list of HRegionInfo, which has getEncodedNameAsBytes() method.